# RNN for regression layers

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I want to train an RNN to solve a simple regression problem. I have an array `X_train` of shape `(35584,)` that represents measures each hour for several years. I also have the correspondent `Y_train` with shape `(35584,)` as the expected values. The values of an hour `h` are affected by values of, say, the previous 6 hours, so I want to use a RNN.

In Keras, I understand that for my case: `timesteps = 6` and `nb_samples = 35584`. In my case, `nb_features = 1`.

How can I program this in Keras? Should I use `Embedding` layer? And how to do it?

Comment: I not sure if this would suit your problem, but you can use simpler Feed Forward Neural Network and with input of size (i.e.) 7 - reading from this hour and 6 previous. In some cases this may be better than using RNNs.

Comment: Thank you, I have already proved (with good results) the standard feed forward approach, but I want to prove with a RNN and also learn how to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I'm going to self answer this question in case it can be useful for someone. How to do a regression with a RNN in Keras it is very well explained here. The blog, besides, has a lot of resources for machine learning and the explanations are superb. Strongly recommended. Link with the explanations of formats, layers, stateful states and so on:

http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/